# How to clean up response files for Solaris packages?

Tags: package-management, solaris

Looking for advice on best way to determine unused entries (or alternatively, used entries) within response files for Solaris packages. Reason is that there are some response files that have suspect entries; ie, entries no longer relevant. Is there any recommended way to determine if a response file has unused entries? New to Solaris packages--many thanks for advice on this.

- Using SunOS 5.10
- Would `pkgadd -v` provide the details on what entries of a response file are being used or not being used?
- Does `pkgchk` help with this?
- How about `pkgparam -v`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague confirmed that `pkgparam` can be used to compare the inputs used at installation time to the inputs of a response file.

The syntax [`pkgparam -v <name of package>`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-7008/6jftmsc3r/index.html) will show actual keys and values that were used, which will include items that do not appear in the response file. Assuming the response file is well-formed (no syntax errors), any bogus keys will be ignored at installation time.